# Python code automatically turning "..." into "…" from excel sheet even when autocorrect is disabled in excel

Tags: python, excel

To be fair, I'm not sure if it's python doing it or excel. But here's my code below:

In `quiz.xlsx`:

```
title
Which of the following is true...
```

In `quiz.py`

```py
filename = 'quiz'
df = pd.read_excel(filename+'.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

for row in df.itertuples():

    title = row.title 

    info = open("info.json","w+")

    info.write('\"title\": \"'+title+'\"')

    info.close()
```

Then it outputs in the .json like so:
`"title": "Which of the following is true…"`

And the output in the website is this: `Which of the following is true�`

That "…" character is showing up as �. I just want a normal three periods, not the special three period character. Unfortunately I can't change how the site shows that special character, because it's not under my jurisdiction.

I've disabled autocorrect and autoreplace in excel, but it's still replacing the "..." with "…" when I run the python script and I'm baffled as to why. (Yes, I know I can simply replace all of these manually but that's hundreds of files and thus I'd prefer to fix it at the root.) Is this a python problem or json or excel?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Python is not doing it. Python doesn't do anything you don't tell it to do explicitly. This one's on excel

Comment: I've disabled and deleted the "replace ... with …" in excel though, and turned off autocorrect. Does .json automatically correct ... with an ellipses?

Comment: No. Json is just a format. Try opening the  file in read only mode in excel. Maybe that'll stop it.

Comment: How do you do read only mode with pandas? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html It doesn't look like there's an option here.

Comment: I meant in excel not pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding an autocorrect option of `replace "..." with "..."`

Apparently even if you delete the `replace "..." with "…"` it will still replace three periods with an ellipses when you exit excel.